# What is the relationship between the e value reported by HMMER and BLAST? (Are they equivalent?)

Tags: sequence-alignment, blast

Both HMMER and BLAST report an e value for alignments.  Is it calculated in the same way and - assuming that default settings are used - can they be compared directly (are the equivalent)?  If not equivalent, what settings can be changed to make them equivalent?

Comment: can  you add some background information so that others less familiar with the question can at least partially follow what is being asked?

Answer (score 3):

They use very different algorithms so they should not have the same E-value. BLAST uses a position-independent substitution matrix (e.g. BLOSUM) while HMMER uses a position-dependent substitution matrix that is different for every profile. Check out the "Background and Brief History" section in the HMMER's user guide. It explains the conceptual differences at a very broad level.

Therefore, I don't think there's any way to make them equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

E-value, in short, is a statistical measure of how likely it is that your sequence of interest could have arisen by **pure chance**. This definition is 'discipline-wide', so should be adhered to by any bioinformatics software that elects to provide it.

Thus, the longer and more complex your sequence is, the better (lower) E-value it will have when conducting sequence alignments.

As far as I am aware, they should be directly comparable. I don't see why they also wouldn't be calculated in exactly the same way.

HMMERs website does state that it utilises 2 different kinds of E-Value however:

> The are then two E-values for the domain:
>
> Conditional E-value - This is the E-value that the inclusion and
> reporting significant thresholds that are measured against (if defined
> as E-values). The conditional E-value is an attempt to measure the
> statistical significance of each domain, given that it has already
> been decided that the target sequence is a true homolog. It is the
> expected number of additional domains or hits that would be found with
> a domain/hit score this big in the set of sequences reported in the
> top hits list, if those sequences consisted only of random
> nonhomologous sequence outside the region that sufficed to define them
> as homologs.
>
> Independent E-value - This is the significance of the
> sequence in the whole database search, if this were the only
> domain/hit that had been identified. If this E-value is not good, but
> the full sequence E-value is good, this is a potential red flag. Weak
> hits, none of which are good enough on their own, are summing up to
> lift the sequence up to a high score.

The calculation for E-Value via BLAST can be found here:

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/BLAST/tutorial/Altschul-1.html